# Django selecting related objects many levels deep

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have these 4 tables in Django:

- Stores (id)

  - Products (id, store_id)
  - Orders (product_id, customer_id)
- Customers (id)

A Store has many products, a product has many orders and an order has one product and one customer.

How would I query in Django to retrieve the distinct list of customers per store? I could easily do it with an SQL query but I would really prefer to go the ORM way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a Store already fetched:

```
customers = Customer.objects.filter(order__product__store=store)
```

Comment: You can also use prefetch_related to fetch the customers when you're getting the store, but I'm not sure how that actually works with multiple levels

Comment: Oh..I didn't know that this style of fetching goes so deep.

Comment: You can go multiple levels deep w/ prefetch_related by calling each relation individually (w/ double underscores)... `customers = Customer.objects.filter(order__product__store=store).prefetch_related('order','order__product','order__product__store')`